# HTML5 Canvas - Add Editable boundries

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, boundary

I want to design tshirt designer application. When I put any tshirt on canvas then I want to restrict user to Edit some part of tshirt by adding Text and all. Please see screen shot and provide me with details.

[image]

Please refer my code here : http://dstudio.edreamz.in/Sample_tshirt_app/Tshirt_test.htm

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2):

Embed the background graphic of the shirt as a normal image in your HTML code. Then create a canvas with the size of the editable area and place it above the image using CSS positioning.

This has the advantage that the canvas is non-destructive to the background. When you erase something on the canvas, the background image beneath it will still be intact.